# Error loading documents in firestore, how can I resolve this issue in Z Scaler

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firewall, zscaler

Hi I'm using firestore for on of my services. But since I'm using company laptop, I'm unable to use firestore.

It is showing the errror, 'error loading documents'.

It is because of Zscaler running behind the system. So I would like to know how we can resolve this.? What urls I need to whitelist? Any other specific things I have to do?

*.googleapis.com is already enabled in the firewall. What other steps I have to take care?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Debug Tests https://debug-my.firebaseapp.com/ to get more information?
Source: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1674#issuecomment-1358465816

The result could help you search more specific. E.g.:

> All tests done. 1: webchannel.googleapis.com with default options:
> FAILED (75094ms) 2: webchannel.googleapis.com with
> detectBufferingProxy: SUCCEEDED (2787ms) 3: webchannel.googleapis.com
> with forceLongPolling: SUCCEEDED (2017ms) 4:
> webchannel.sandbox.google.com with default options: FAILED (75010ms)
> 5: webchannel.sandbox.google.com with detectBufferingProxy: SUCCEEDED
> (2819ms) 6: webchannel.sandbox.google.com with forceLongPolling:
> SUCCEEDED (2151ms) 7: Firestore listen test with default options:
> FAILED (75035ms) 8: Firestore listen test with detectBufferingProxy:
> SUCCEEDED (1341ms) 9: Firestore listen test with forceLongPolling:
> SUCCEEDED (509ms)